# starmap, starmap_async python

Tags: python, parallel-processing, starmap

I want to translate a huge matlab model to python. Therefor I need to work on the key functions first. One key function handles parallel processing. Basically, a matrix with parameters is the input, in which every row represents the parameters for one run. These parameters are used within a computation-heavy function. This computation-heavy function should run in parallel, I don't need the results of a previous run for any other run. So all processes can run independent from eachother.

Why is starmap_async slower on my pc? Also: When i add more code (to test consecutive computation) my python crashes (i use spyder). Can you give me advice?

```
import time
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing as mp
from functools import partial

# Create simulated data matrix
data = np.random.random((100,3000))
data = np.column_stack((np.arange(1,len(data)+1,1),data))

def EAF_DGL(*z, package_num):
    sum_row = 0
    for i in range(1,np.shape(z)[0]):
        sum_row = sum_row + z[i] 
    func_result = np.column_stack((package_num,z[0],sum_row))
    return func_result


t0 = time.time()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    package_num = 1
    help_EAF_DGL = partial(EAF_DGL, package_num=1)
    with mp.Pool() as pool:
        #result = pool.starmap(partial(EAF_DGL, package_num), [(data[i]) for i in range(0,np.shape(data)[0])])
        result = pool.starmap_async(help_EAF_DGL, [(data[i]) for i in range(0,np.shape(data)[0])]).get()
    pool.close() 
    pool.join()
t1 = time.time()
calculation_time_parallel_async = t1-t0
print(calculation_time_parallel_async)

t2 = time.time()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    package_num = 1
    help_EAF_DGL = partial(EAF_DGL, package_num=1)
    with mp.Pool() as pool:
        #result = pool.starmap(partial(EAF_DGL, package_num), [(data[i]) for i in range(0,np.shape(data)[0])])
        result = pool.starmap(help_EAF_DGL, [(data[i]) for i in range(0,np.shape(data)[0])])
    pool.close() 
    pool.join()
t3 = time.time()
calculation_time_parallel = t3-t2
print(calculation_time_parallel)
```